# The new Closed As Duplicate Banner should be more official

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Whether or not one agrees with the new closing guidelines, there is one startling nuance about the UI that is causing some interesting behavior: because the banners aren't a part of the actual post, newbies think that moderators or other users tack them up there.  This would create a feeling of frustration in new users who would automatically assume that those closing the question are also editing his "work" to throw up a relatively large banner proclaiming that the question might be invalid.

I propose that the new dupe banners include a tagline on the banner itself that mentions that they are either generated by SE, or a link to somewhere in the FAQ explaining what they are in the first place and why they cannot be edited away.

Comment: I would post an example, but I don't want to end up violating the [trademark guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: Has this concern been expressed? The banner's appearance is mostly the same as the old dupe banner. Did people think the old one was edited in by mean power users?

Comment: Uh... They *do* come from moderators and other users. Just because they're not *edited* in doesn't mean they don't come to exist as a direct result of community moderator actions.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Why would that violate the trademark guidelines? We're on an offical SE site here, so for sure that wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @Shog9 It's not really that that I take issue with, it's that users assume it's vandalism on our parts,

Comment: @CodaFi: I've never seen this problem.